# Discord, why is the server emoji author null?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

On any server I pick the author property of emoji is now null, why could that be ?
Does it have something to do with my bot's permissions ?

```
{
  "animated": false,
  "name": "d53589c38c2a8b20f24976899b0edf0a",
  "id": "899427561174622239",
  "deleted": false,
  "guildID": "843112700561326111",
  "requireColons": null,
  "managed": false,
  "available": true,
  "requiresColons": true,
  "author": null,
  "createdTimestamp": 1634510641140,
  "url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/899427561174622239.png",
  "identifier": "d53589c38c2a8b20f24976899b0edf0a:899427561174622239"
}
```

[image: server 1]
[image: server 2]

Comment: So there's no author information in any of the places you've looked. So what? Please explain what you're trying to do (with code), how this lack of data is a problem, and how you think we can help.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/Emoji.js#L25

The only author mentions in discord js code I found are

```
class Emoji extends Base {
  constructor(client, emoji) {
    super(client, data, guild);

    /**
     * The user who created this emoji
     * @type {?User}
     */
    this.author = null;

    ...

   _patch(data) {
      super._patch(data);

      if (data.user) this.author = this.client.users._add(data.user);
      if (data.roles) this._roles = data.roles;
    }

   }
}
```